# What is a kernel integral operator?

Tags: measure-theory, integral-transforms

I was reading a paper that define the kernel integral operator as follows:

> We define the kernel integral operator $\mathcal{K}$. Let $\kappa^{(l)} \in C(D \times D; \mathbb{R}^{d_{l+1} \times d_l})$ and let $\nu$ be a Borel measure on $D$. Then we define $\mathcal{K}$ by $$(\mathcal{K}v_l)(x) = \int_D \kappa^{(l)}(x, y)v_l(y)d\nu(y) \qquad \forall x \in D.$$

What does the kernel integral operator do? What is $C(D \times D; \mathbb{R}^{d_{l+1} \times d_l})$? What is a Borel measure?

Comment: A Borel measure is a measure on the Borel $\sigma-$algebra. I believe your D is a topological space. So The Borel $\sigma-$algebra is the $\sigma-$algebra generated by the open sets of $D$.

Answer (score 3):

To answer what a Borel measure is in a concise way, one has to make use of a lot of concepts in measure theory.

Let $D$ be a [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space), with topology $\tau$. This is the collection of all open sets of $D$. The $\sigma$-algebra on $D$ generated by $\tau$ is called the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. A Borel measure is a measure on this $\sigma$-algebra.

The notation $C(D\times D; \mathbb{R}^{d_{\ell+1}\times _{\ell}})$ usually means the space of *continuous* functions $f: D \times D \to \mathbb{R}^{d_{\ell+1}\times d_{\ell}}$. Here, the topology on $D \times D$ is the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).

The idea of an integral kernel is that it defines an integral operator. Roughly speaking, one can define an operator over some function space by integrating each element of this function space across some well-behaved function. In other words:
$$T: \varphi \mapsto (T\varphi)(x) := \int k(x,y)\varphi(y)dy$$
provided these objects are well-defined and understood.

Intuitively, it is the "functional" or "continuous" version of a matrix multiplication operator. Given a vector $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, an $N\times N$ matrix $M = (M_{ij})$ can be viewed as an operator:
$$M: \varphi \mapsto (M\varphi)_{i} := \sum_{ij}M_{ij}\varphi_{j}$$
In this simple case, the indices are just positive integers. An integral operator plays the role of the matrix when the "indices become continuous variables". This is, of course, just pictoric, but is the intuition used by physicist most of the time when they use integral operators.

Comment: Is there a way to go from a matrix multiplication operator $M$ to its "continuous version" $T$? What about the other direction? Are they equal at some fixed points?

Comment: @user572780 Sometimes it is possible to do both directions by discretization and than taking limits. Maybe an example is the Laplacian operator, which can be "discretized" in such a way that one recovers its original definition when taking continuum limits. I know mathematical physicists use this a lot in quantum field theory and statistical mechanics.